# Provider com.sun.faces.util.cdi11.CDIUtilImpl not a subtype while deploying in Glassfish 5.1

Tags: java, spring-boot, glassfish-5

I am getting below issue while deploying Spring boot application (.ear extension) in Glassfish 5.1

Issue : Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.sun.faces.util.cdi11.CDIUtil: Provider com.sun.faces.util.cdi11.CDIUtilImpl not a subtype
at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)

Can someone please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in Advance...!!!